# Error creating NuGet package for Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, portable-class-library, win-universal-app

I'm new to Nuget and I'm trying to create a NuGet package for a Portable Class Library project that has a package dependency on another portable class library I've created.

I'm running into an issue where I'm receiving an error when calling **nuget pack** for the project file **TestComponent2.csproj** (I created this from the Portable for Universal Apps template in VS 2013). This library has a dependency on a nuget package created from another PCL called **TestComponent1**.

The package created never seems to contain this dependency (the console output even says "Dependencies: None"). However it is in the packages.config file for the **TestComponent2** project the dependency is definitely listed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="TestComponent1" version="1.0" targetFramework="portable-win81+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

So in my situation I'm calling the following from the command line for a project called TestComponent2, from the folder containing the TestComponent2.csproj and packages.config, with verbosity turned on:

```
> nuget pack TestComponent2.csproj -Verbosity Detailed
```

WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from 'TestComponent2.dll'.
WARNING: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection,
Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, B
oolean suppressSecurityChecks)

...

Add file 'mypath\TestComponent2.dll' to package as 'lib\portable-win81+wpa81\TestComponent2.dll'

Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
WARNING: Description was not specified. Using 'Description'.
WARNING: Author was not specified. Using 'myname'.

Id: TestComponent2
Version: 1.0
Authors: myname
Description: Description
Dependencies: None

Added file 'lib\portable-win81+wpa81\TestComponent2.dll'.

Successfully created package 'mypath\TestComponent2.1.0.nupkg'.

If I call **nuget spec** first I also get the following error:
WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from 'TestComponent2.dll'.
Using 'TestComponent2.nuspec' for metadata.
The replacement token 'title' has no value.

Is there an issue with nuget creating packages for the new universal PCL? Or perhaps I have some configuration wrong? I'm using Nuget 2.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there is a [bug in NuGet 2.8](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4013) causing it to fail to read the metadata from a PCL assembly.

I was going to suggest you try an older version of NuGet but unfortunately I think you need 2.8.1 since you are using the Windows Phone Application target (wpa) which is only supported in 2.8.1 or above.

A workaround would be to use **nuget pack YourNuSpecFile.nuspec** instead of using the project file. However you will need to put more information in the .nuspec to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, so I will need to specify the dependencies directly in the nuspec file, rather than having them picked up automatically by  reading packages.config?

Comment: Yes. Everything would need to go into the .nuspec file due to the bug.

Comment: There is a link to the bug in the answer

Comment: I tried with 3.2 version and it is with the same bug. Can anybody help me?

Comment: NuGet 2.8.6 does not work for me. Version 3.3.0 is fine.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is [patched in 3.0.0](https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/StephenCleary/Issue4013/contribution/6798#!/tab/changes)

until 3.0.0 is released, I have created [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/patsissons/nugetpclissue) that contains a patched executable that I have been using for the past few months. The repository also contains a sample project to better visualize the issue and how it can occur under simple, yet unexpected circumstances.

A direct link to the executable is here: https://bitbucket.org/patsissons/nugetpclissue/src/HEAD/.nuget-patched/NuGet.exe?at=master

Comment: I'm still getting this error. Nuget Package Manager thinks it installed PCL successfully but the dll never gets installed. It only has an entry in packages.config. Hence, I am looking at the references in Solution Explorer and it does not reflect the added dll for a pcl.

Comment: @pjs. I have just tried the beta version of 3.1 and it has the same bug! This is the executable they offer:  http://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v3.1.0-beta/nuget.exe

Comment: I'm afraid that with the new 3.1 version, they restored some coded or missed it. Unfortunately, I cannot find the part of the code that has te bug (the file structure in 3.0+ is different, I think) and I cloned the project but it's incompatible with VS 2015. Could you please take a look? Big thanks!

Comment: The patch still exists in their NuGet2 repo: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/dev/src/Core/Authoring/AssemblyMetadataExtractor.cs#L69

but the NuGet.PackageManagement repo doesn't appear to contain this class (i could trace it to here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.PackageManagement/blob/dev/src/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands/ProjectFactory.cs#L138 )

I ran their beta CLI through a reflector and could confirm that they did not port the patch over to the v3 code base.

Comment: I tried with 3.2 version and it is with the same bug. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This bug is STILL in verison 4.6.2.5055 of NuGet.exe!