# NuGet pack: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0'

Tags: .net, nuget

There seems to be a problem with NuGet that prevents me from generating packages for portable class libraries (PCL) that target Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (Profile32).

NuGet Version: 2.8.60318.667

My directory contains a single .csproj file, and a companion .nuspec that provides metadata.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenLiekens/HTTPortable/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/StevenLiekens/HTTPortable</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>The MIT License (MIT)</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When I run `nuget.exe pack` in that directory, the program crashes with an error.

> > nuget pack

```
Attempting to build package from 'HTTPortable.Tcp.WinRT.csproj'.
Packing files from 'D:\src\HTTPortable\src\HTTPortable.Tcp.WinRT\src\bin\Debug'.
WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from 'HTTPortable.Tcp.WinRT.dll'.
Using 'HTTPortable.Tcp.WinRT.nuspec' for metadata.
The replacement token 'title' has no value.
```

Detailed logging reveals that nuget.exe is trying to load an assembly that doesn't exist.

> > nuget pack /verbosity detailed

```
WARNING: Unable to extract metadata from 'HTTPortable.Tcp.WinRT.dll'.
WARNING: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(String assemblyString)
   at NuGet.AssemblyMetadataExtractor.MetadataExtractor.AssemblyResolver.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternalCore(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr[] typeInstantiationContext, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr[] methodInstantiationContext, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData..ctor(RuntimeModule scope, CustomAttributeRecord caRecord)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tkTarget)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributesInternal(RuntimeAssembly target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributesData()
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly target)
   at NuGet.AssemblyMetadataExtractor.MetadataExtractor.GetMetadata(String path)
   at NuGet.AssemblyMetadataExtractor.MetadataExtractor.GetMetadata(String path)
   at NuGet.AssemblyMetadataExtractor.GetMetadata(String assemblyPath)
   at NuGet.AssemblyMetadataExtractor.ExtractMetadata(PackageBuilder builder, String assemblyPath)
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath)
```

Does this look familiar to anyone?

Comment: It is a bug in NuGet. See this StackOverflow question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676953/error-creating-nuget-package-for-portable-class-library

Comment: Soo... I guess the solution is to wait for nuget 3.0.0?

Comment: Or you can apply the fix to NuGet and build it locally. The fix is two lines of code - https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/StephenCleary/Issue4013/contribution/6798

Comment: PS: nuget 3 is out and it still has the same bug in it !

Comment: @StevenLiekens Has there been any resolution to this since Oct '15?

Comment: @PaulDiston yes I believe this was fixed in nuget 3.3. See: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1514. Resolved by commit: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/commit/a07f5cba2437c1e6b0ff23781a20c2327fce45a9.